# Apache Nifi Flowfile to Elasticsearch bulk api

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi, bulk, flowfile

I'm trying to prepare flowfile to make bulk call with versioning to elasticsearch using standard InvokeHttp processor, since I failed to make it work with PutElasticsearch* processors

Elasticsearch bulk endpoint accept ndjson data format that looks like follow:

```
{"index": {"_index":"foo","id":"bar", "version":1, "version_type":"external}}\n
{"id":"bar", "version":1, "field1":"field1_value", "field2":"field2_value"}\n

{"index": {"_index":"foo","id":"bizz", "version":2, "version_type":"external}}\n
{"id":"bizz", "version":2, "field1":"field3_value", "field2":"field4_value"}\n
```

My current setup of processors looks like follow:
[Change to elasticsearch bulk format flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJAQk.png)

I'm extracting id to attribute, version to attribute and flowfile content to attribute `message.body` using ExtractText processor with simple regex `.*`,

With content in attribute I can then use ConvertRecord processor with RecordReader: `JsonTreeReader`
and RecordWriter: `FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter` with Text property set to:

```
{"index": {"_index":"foo","_id":"${id}", "version":"${version", "version_type":"external"}}}
${message.body}
```

Having flowfiles converted now I merge them using MergeContent processor, and sending them to elasticsearch by InvokeHttp processor with url set to ${elastic.url}/foo/_bulk and Content-Type set to x-ndjson type.

Is it possible to make it better? I have this feeling that my solution is not best one, but I'm Newby to Nifi and I couldn't solve it in other way.